# Método para devolver un entero retorna null

Tags: java

Quería documentar una prueba con junit y deseaba probar un método sencillo. El método a probar lee un entero y lo devuelve. Si el valor no es entero captura la Excepción y realiza nueva petición hasta hallar el valor deseado

```
public static int leerInteger(){ 
                                 
        int d=0;                     
        boolean  flag=false;  
        Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in);
                   
            do{        
                try{
                    System.out.println("Inserte un entero");       
                    d=entrada.nextInt();  
                    flag=true;                                                
                    }
                catch(InputMismatchException e){
                    System.out.println("Error en la inserción"); 
                    entrada.nextLine();
                }              
            } while(!flag);                       
                      
        return d;
                        
}
```

El resultado de la prueba en el que se ha usado un método `assertEquals()` es fallido. Al realizar la prueba el sistema no se detiene tras el uso de Scanner de la forma en la que lo haría usando el método que se desea probar, sino que devuelve un `null` directamente y obviamente el resultado esperado, 0 no es el mismo que el obtenido, `null`. Y, alguien podría decirme que es preciso para que el resultado sea satisfactorio si el método a probar recibe un entero¿

```
public class IO_ESTest {
    
    public IO_ESTest() {
    }
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }
    
    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }
    
    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of leerInteger method, of class IO_ES.
     */
    @Test
    public void testLeerInteger_0args() {
        System.out.println("leerInteger");
        int expResult = 0;
        int result = IO_ES.leerInteger();
        assertEquals(expResult, result);
       // TODO review the generated test code and remove the default call to 
       //fail.
       //fail("The test case is a prototype.");
       }
     }
```

Comment: El código es texto y se debe compartir como tal, las imágenes son para... bueno, imágenes. Edita la pregunta y pon tu código como texto, por favor. Te recomiendo repasar [ask] y hacer el [tour] o revisar la ayuda para que entiendas cómo formular una pregunta correcta en StackOverflow, pues con tu reputación deberías saber ya de sobra que aquí una imagen de código no es aceptable!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JUnit se usa para tests automatizados de unidad, y como tal no toca que se quede esperando a que el usuario introduzca un valor por stdin.

Sospecho que lo que hace junit es por defecto cerrar la entrada estandar (*stdin*) y por eso te devuelve *null*.

Hay varias opciones para solucionarlo:

#### java.lang.System.setIn(InputStream)

Hay un [método en java.lang.System](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setIn(java.io.InputStream)) que te permite asignar una instancia de InputStream. Le pasas una instancia que implemente los métodos que vas a usar y devuelva los valores esperados, y listo. Se puede considerar un *mockup*, y de hecho es probable que puedas crear uno con alguno de los frameworks de *mockup* requeridos.

#### Inyectar un wrapper

Tu método no usa directamente *System.in* sino una instancia de una clase tuya, que le pasas (por constructor, setter, como parámetro, etc). La implementación habitual llama a *System.in*, pero para hacer el test usas otra implementación que no usa *System.in*.

Se podría considerar que este sistema y el anterior son equivalentes, con este último un poco más "formal"

#### Independizar tu lógica del IU.

Si tienes un método que suma dos números, saca la lógica de preguntar los números fuera del método. Simplemente que tu método acepte los dos números como parámetros y ejecute la lógica. En tu programa, obtienes los números desde *stdin* y los pasas al método, desde el junit pasas dos valores fijos para luego verificar que el resultado funcione.

En general recomendaría este sistema, ya que es más elegante, sencillo, y te sirve para tener una lógica más flexible (puedes usar el mismo método si los números te vienen desde un GUI, por ejemplo).

En tu caso en concreto igual las opciones 1 ó 2 funcionarían. En todo caso atención que la idea de las pruebas *unitarias* es probar solo tu lógica, con independencia del resto del sistema, y eso es complicado con el ejemplo que muestras ya que no hay mucho que probar salvo que pongas mockups de *System.in*. Casi parece que estás probando más la lógica de *nextInt*, y no es eso lo que se pretende.

Si estás empezando te recomendaría que probarás con métodos más "lógicos", sin interfaz de usuario, para familiarizarte.

Comment: Gracias...miraré lo de mockups!

Comment: *Independizar tu lógica del IU.* Siempre este. La lógica ***siempre*** debería ir *aislada* de lo demás, no solo facilita el testeo, tal como explica perfectamente la respuesta, si no que el día que necesitas modificar algo no tienes que revisar los 50 archivos llenos de código de la interfaz donde hay lógica entremezclada... con lo cual, en algún sitio se te olvidará actualizar tu lógica y tendrás dos comportamientos diferentes!! Para mockups en java, con JUnit se suele usar Mockito  a menudo :)